# Swagger ui RangeError: Maximum call stack size exceeded in FastAPI

Tags: python, swagger-ui, fastapi

In my `FastAPI` project's Swagger UI, when I execute an API after a while I get this error:

> RangeError: Maximum call stack size exceeded in FastAPI

When I check the *Network* tab in browser's inspect, I can see that the status code is 200 and I can view the result response there. But the loading icon is still spinning in Swagger UI and after a while I get that error.

**UPDATE**

After lots of investigations, I realized that [Swagger UI has issue with large responses](https://github.com/swagger-api/swagger-ui/issues/3832) (2MB+ in my case ).

I tried this:

```
app = FastAPI(
        swagger_ui_parameters={'syntaxHighlight.theme': 'obsidian'}
)
```

But it didn't work.

Does anyone has any idea how to do it right?

Comment: I am getting same. did you get any solution?

Comment: @UpasanaMittal The solution I suggest works now in new versions of FastAPI

Comment: Thanks. Setting `swagger_ui_parameters={'syntaxHighlight': False}`worked for me. I think you can move your updated information into an answer to this question.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I found out that one solution for this is to disable the syntax highlight in [Swagger configurations](https://swagger.io/docs/open-source-tools/swagger-ui/usage/configuration/). So I tried to [deactivate it with FastAPI](https://github.com/tiangolo/fastapi/pull/2568/files) like this:

```
app = FastAPI(
        swagger_ui_parameters={'syntaxHighlight': False}
)
```

And it's working now.